# Checking the nature of the sequence ${x_{n}}=\frac{\left\lfloor xn \right\rfloor}{n}$ **[TIFR GS-2011]**

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**[TIFR GS-2011, Q1.]**

> Consider the sequence ${x_{n}}$ defined by $\frac{\left\lfloor xn
> \right\rfloor}{n}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
>
> (A) Converges to $x$.
>
> (B) Converges not to $x$.
>
> (C) doesn't converge.
>
> (D) oscillate.

When I take $x=1$ sequence converges to $1$. similarly I had given particular values to $x$, I am not able to judge the answer. Can any one help me to figure out the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac{\lfloor xn
\rfloor}{n}=\frac{xn}{n}-\frac{\{xn\}}{n}$

Comment: Note that $\lfloor{xn}\rfloor$ is within $1$ of $xn$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_n=\frac{\lfloor xn\rfloor}{n}=\frac{xn-\{xn\}}{n}=x-\frac{\{xn\}}{n}\to x\text{ as }n\to\infty,$$
where $\{y\}\in[0,1)$ is the fractional part of $y$. Therefore, the answer is (A).